# iPad 3 slow screenshot

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, screenshot, retina-display

In my app I'm using a screenshot method. On my iPad 2 it's very fast (about 130 ms) to execute this method. But on the new iPad (certainly due to the highest resolution and the same CPU) it's taking like 700 ms ! Is there a way to optimize my method ? Perhaps there's a way to work directly with graphic card ?

Here's my screenshot method :

```
- (UIImage *)image {
CGSize imageSize = self.bounds.size;

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [self center].x, [self center].y);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, [self transform]);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -[self bounds].size.width * [[self layer] anchorPoint].x, -[self bounds].size.height * [[self layer] anchorPoint].y);
[[self layer] renderInContext:context];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't help you here. But I think that 700ms is really slow. Shouldn't it be like 130ms * 4 = 520ms?

Comment: Try using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0f);` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);`.
This will make for 1:1 screenshot. Or is there a specific reason you need `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` there?

Comment: @Jenox yeah it depends but it's more like 700ms.

Comment: @Rokjarc Thank you. It's still slow :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that it isnt going to be 520ms.  Lets remember that between the iPad 2 and 3 they quadrupled the pixels, but only doubled the graphics horspower and left the CPU the same.  I think it is perhaps feasible that 700 ms might actually be the best you may get for a screenshot of full resolution

Comment: @trumpetlicks yes. So now I'm taking screenshots with un retina resolution and then I'm stretching them to retina resolution.

Comment: well then in this case I would FULLY expect more than 520ms.  For a simple screenshot thats one thing, but when you are actually having to process a smaller image and mathematically generate for the more pixels, thats very processing heavy!!!

Comment: @Pierre I found the same issue and opted for the same solution: taking the screenshot at half the resolution for the new iPad. In that way I get reasonable speed and, due to the nature of the animation I do with the screenshot, the loss in quality is almost non-noticeable. Just to mention that I don't find this problem with the iPhone 4 or 4S, they take retina screenshots just fine.

Comment: This piece of code actually works, but it doesn't take into account device orientation?

Comment: The resource at this link helped me find the way to compensate for device orienation http://i-gorod.org/itblog/2013/02/28/ios-screen-capture-depending-on-device-orientation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it was the developer of Flipboard talking about this issue on a podcast. It is a real issue with the iPad 3, because they've quadrupled the pixels.

What he was doing was taking the screenshot ahead of time in the background, not when the user initiated the action - in his case when the user "flipped" the page.

I don't know whether this will help you in your case, but it is certainly a viable approach for many cases.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be sufficient for your application but one option is to scale the screenshot down, e.g. pass 0.5 as your scale factor to **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions**. 4x faster but the tradeoff is a loss of detail/resolution.